# Can a character detect when Presence is used on them?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-dark-ages

I'm about to begin an V20 Dark Ages crossover game and I'm anticipating a PC using the Vampiric Discipline Presence while performing for a crowd (which will include several other PCs) in the upcoming session.

There will be several Vampires (roughly 9th generation), a couple of Hedge Mages, and several Ghouls in the audience.

My main concern is Auspex, but I assume if one is not actively using it when she uses the Discipline (or surveying the aftermath with a well-trained or expectant eye) they would see very little that is unusual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not while it's happening, elsewise the Discipline wouldn't be of much use. The target feels the emotions as though they were real. However, once the effect fades, it's reasonable (perhaps with an Occult check if not familiar with Kindred lore) to deduce that the emotions were supernaturally incited. And spectators — those not under the discipline's effects — can use the Awareness talent to identify a supernatural power being used.

Comment: I cannot remember if and where its noted in the TT books, but it is noted in the LARP books that even after the effect fades, only those with experience with presence might even suspect that its been used on them.  There is no challenge/test to see if its been used on you (save some obscure thaumaturgy) - you can just suspect it.

Comment: @Tritium21 I think I recall something similar, but that's an affordance for LARP, where both the subject and the target of the discipline are likely to be player characters and challenges are minimized to maintain flow. I have confidence in my answer as regards the tabletop game's scope.